# Condição Yoda, boa razão existe para usar?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação

Pergunta principalmente em PHP, na documentação do WordPress existe [um trecho](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions) que fala explicitamente que é interessante usar as famosas condições Yoda, apesar de não dar um bom e real motivo.

> Ao fazer comparações lógicas envolvendo variáveis, coloque sempre a
> variável no lado direito e coloque constantes, literais ou chamadas de
> função no lado esquerdo. (Tradução Livre)

Especificamente eu, sempre achei feio e de leitura não fácil esse tipo de codificação: `if(10 == $teste){ // do anything }` ou `if("string" == $teste){ // do anything }`

Essa duvida me surgiu apos um colega meu me recomendar instalar um plugin no brackets chamado [brackets php code quality tools](https://github.com/mikaeljorhult/brackets-php-code-quality-tools) que teoricamente aponta erros na codificação... e em linhas do tipo `if($teste == 10){ // do anything }` ele gera warnings, ele recomenda o uso das benditas condições Yoda.

A primeira vez que eu vi esse tipo de codificação me veio em mente ser para facilitar o processamento, tipo primeiro o processador somente pega a constante e depois acessa o local da variável na memoria, mas parando pra pensar não vejo nenhuma diferença!

Fiz testes em PHP e JavaScript e não vi nenhuma diferença de performance a olho nu...

Segue testes:

## PHP

```
echo "Normal<br/>";
$a = "a";
for($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++){
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    if($a == "a"){
        //
    }
    $execution_time = microtime(true) - $time_start;
    echo $execution_time.'s<br/>';
}
echo "-------------<br/>";
echo "Yoda Condition<br/>";
$a = "a";
for($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++){
    $time_start = microtime(true); 
    if("a" == $a){
        //
    }
    $execution_time = microtime(true) - $time_start;
    echo $execution_time.'s<br/>';
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## JavaScript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma boa razão pra se usar Yoda Conditions em alguma linguagem de programação? Ou é apenas a gosto do cliente? Existe alguma diferença de performance (em alguma linguagem)?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Usando condição Yoda a pergunta elaborada foi. Bom padawan você é.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A unica vantagem das yoda conditions é **trocar o tipo do erro**, de lógica (atribuição no lugar da comparação) por um de sintaxe. Não é possível atribuir algo diretamente em um número ou qualquer outro tipo.

Basicamente yoda conditions fazem o código falhar mais rápido em caso de erros enquanto a performace ainda é a mesma comparação; logo não afeta em nada.

Será que vale a pena sacrificar a legibilidade para detectar esse tipo de erro mais cedo? É um erro simples que as vezes pode causar um pouco de dor de cabeça, nessas situações o melhor é fazer uma pausa e esfriar a cabeça.

```
<?php
$usuario = 'teste';
if('admin' = $nome){
    echo 'administrador do sistema';
}
```

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '='

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/h8FKTr)

Comment: Andei pesquisando e achei um site que diz que muitos programadores (inclusive eu) acham que os **benefícios** não são tao grandes assim.... se a condição tiver uma atribuição invés de uma comparação, de qualquer jeito vai ter um erro rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio também não não acho legal yoda conditions. Qual dos dois é mais fácil de achar um erro de lógica ou de sintaxe? :P É a unica vantagem (adiantar o erro) veja que isso sacrifica a legibilidade. Será que vale a pena mesmo? eu acho que não.

Comment: Pois então veja..... você vai la, escreve o código correto `if(a == "a"){` e o bendito plugin que ate da umas dicas bacanas e ajuda bastante vai la e solta uma warning..... não sei nem o que falar!

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Troca o plugin :P imagino que tenha uma opção para ignorar essa regra especifica.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Eu só sugeriria melhorar a frase (que não ficou clara, a não ser que a sua intenção também era brincar de Yoda rs) "*Basicamente yoda conditions fazem o código falhar mais rápido quanto a performace ainda é a mesma comparação logo não afeta em nada.*" para algo do tipo "*Basicamente yoda conditions fazem o código falhar mais rápido **em caso de erros de digitação**, enquanto a performace **de comparação é mantida** a mesma; logo não afeta em nada **na execução***."

Comment: @LuizVieira Obrigado pela sugestão, edita a resposta :)

Comment: Curiosamente, uma empresa perdeu recentemente cerca de 1 milhão de reais por cometer um erro inverso a esse. Ao invés de atribuir um valor a uma variável, o trecho do código comparava se os dois valores eram iguais. Para quem estiver interessado, o [link](https://zcoin.io/language/en/zcoins-zerocoin-bug-explained-in-detail/).

Answer (score 9):

Em Java usa-se algo parecido para comparações envolvendo uma string literal (entre aspas) ou outro objeto já instanciado:

```
if ("Mario".equals(nome)) {
```

A utilidade é economizar um teste de referência nula. Se o programador não quiser fazer essa checagem ou esquecer de fazê-la, mas estiver acostumado a inverter a condição, poderá evitar uma `NullPointerException` que poderia ocorrer caso chamasse `equals()` a partir de uma referência nula.

Answer (score 4):

A vantagem da Yoda conditions é de expor possíveis bugs por erros de digitação, trocando um `==` por `=`.

No código abaixo, a condição sempre irá retornar `true`, causando um comportamento inesperado na aplicação - que poderia levar algum tempo para ser descoberto.

```
<?php
$usuario = 'teste';
if($usuario = 'admin'){
    echo 'administrador do sistema';
}
?>
```

Utilizando a yoda condition, você receberia um erro de sintaxe ao executar esse código, percebendo e corrigindo o problema imediatamente.

```
<?php
$usuario = 'teste';
if('admin' = $usuario){
    echo 'administrador do sistema';
}
?>
```

Assim você tem um ganho de performance não na execução do código, mas na prevenção bugs.