# Duvida sobre logica, ifs com múltiplas checagens

Tags: java

Tenho um código onde preciso verificar se duas entradas são verdadeiras.

Eu estou fazendo assim:

```
if (!estudante.getOutTotal.equals("0") && !estudante.getOutEmAtendimento.equals.("0")) {
    // Faz algo...
    itens.add(estudante);
}
```

Caso os totais de emAtendimento e OutEmAtendimento forem valores "0" não quero adicionar na minha lista agora nessa situação poderia ocorrer que outEmAtendimento seja "0" mas outTotal seja "50"... nesse caso seria necessário adicionar na lista mas essa lógica não faz isso.

Eu fiz isso:

```
if (!estudante.getOutTotal.equals("0") && !estudante.getOutEmAtendimento.equals.("0")) {
    // Faz algo...
    itens.add(estudante);
} else if (!estudante.getOutTotal.equals("0") || !estudante.getOutEmAtendimento.equals.("0")) {
    // Faz algo...
    itens.add(estudante);
}
```

Então para não excluir de todos eu verifico se ou um ou outro não é zero se não adiciono na lista.

Está certo? Há alguma maneira melhor de fazer?

---

A principio dei uma melhorada básica e funcionou conforme eu esperava.

Segue:

```
if (!estudante1.equals("0") && !estudante2.equals("0")) {
  itens.add(estudante1);
  itens.add(estudante2);
  System.out.println("1 if");

} else if (!estudante1.equals("0") || !estudante2.equals("0")) {
  itens.add(estudante1);
  System.out.println("2 if");
  itens.add(estudante2);

}
```

Comment: Aline, dica de quem já sofreu muito nessa vida de Java: use as constantes do lado esquerdo do `equals`. Tipo, `"0".equals(estudante.getOutTotal())`. Pode não ser o seu caso, mas no geral isso evita NPEs. Outro ponto que achei estranho, quando você coloca o nome do método com o fim `Total` eu espero ter um valor numérico; se isso for verdade, comparar um número com uma `String` retorna falso, visto que são elementos de classes distintas; reiterando: achei estranho, mas depende de mais contexto para afirmar se está correto

Comment: você pode fazer o seguinte, se entendi bem, você tem dois casos, onde se ambos forem verdadeiros você deseja fazer nada, mas se um deles forem verdadeiro e o outro falso, você deseja fazer algo,  então você poderia colocar um if mais abrangente no caso getOutTotal, se ele fosse verdadeiro (valor 0) você colocaria mais 2 ifs dentro dele, um para verificar se o getOutEmAtendimento é verdadeiro e outro para verificar se ele é falso. acredito que assim você cubra todas as possibilidades

Comment: Isso que o @JeffersonQuesado comentou se chama condição Yoda, se quiser saber mais, [veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187901/14262)

Comment: Achei o seu parágrafo falando das condições confuso. Nele você cita o valor 50, mas não tem em parte alguma do código de exemplo menção ao 50. Também está tarde onde estou, o sono não me deixa tentar interpretar significados

Comment: Sua logica não faz la muito sentido, pense assim:
`Se(condicaoTal) Faça { Escreva "Oi" } Senão { Escreva "Oi" }`
De qualquer jeito ira fazer a mesma coisa `Escreva "Oi"`, isso poderia ser otimizado apenas com `Se(condicaoTal) Faça { Escreva "Oi" }`, por enquanto nem estrou entrando em questão da pergunta em si, somente a primeira coisa estranha que enxerguei

Comment: @MarceloBoni , pensei que fosse só boa prática. Vou até compartilhar seu comentário falando da comparação Yoda lá no trabalho

Comment: Espera, vouo abrir o eclipse e escrever direito. Só um instante.

Comment: A princípio, como se `getOutEmAtendimento` *OU* `getOutTotal` for diferente de zero, a ação é a mesma: `itens.add(estudante);`, o primeiro `if` é desnecessário. O pessoal está vendo vários possíveis problemas no seu código, então o ideal seria que você incluísse outras informações, por exemplo, o tipo da variável `getOutTotal`, ou o resto da sua classe... ;)

Comment: Gente! funcionou!

Comment: Certo! Irei revisá-lo novamente espera...

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado, só não sei com o que ainda... no código que você pôs após a edição, ele padecia mais direto ao assunto, mais organizado, mas ainda não identifiquei onde ou porquê aconteceu a correção

Comment: Jefferson Quesado, eu irei ter que fazer parse. É assim que eles trabalham lá...de String para Integer...

Comment: Rapaz é assim caso retorne valores zerados eu não vou acrescentar na minha listView para ser exibida lá 0,  eu prefiro não acrescentar no listview...desculpa aí qualquer coisa...

Comment: To fazendo tipo um relatório para android. :3

Comment: MarceloBoni percebi isso agora eu achava que o símbolo && fazia exclusão caso fossem dois valores diferentes... por exemplo estudante1 = 0 mas estudante2 = 34. por isso coloquei assim com dois ifs...opa espera mas faz. É só colocar um || que resolve o problema. E excluo o primeiro if. Ah entendi. mas estou com sono estou me atrapalhando...aff voltar para o eclipse

Comment: Eu achava que o operador || excluía do 'processamento' caso fossem duas posições verdadeiras...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha opinião. Sucintamente, bastaria isso:

```
if (!"0".equals(estudante1.getOutTotal())){
  itens.add(estudante1);
}
if (!"0".equals(estudante2.getOutTotal())){
  itens.add(estudante2);
}
```

---

E caso apenas um das condições bastasse para que fosse adicionada nas duas listagens:

```
if (!"0".equals(estudante1.getOutTotal())){
  itens.add(estudante1);
  itens.add(estudante2);
}
if (!"0".equals(estudante2.getOutTotal())){
  itens.add(estudante1);
  itens.add(estudante2);
}
```

Comment: blz garoto....valeu.