# O que significa o termo typeof module, em javascript?

Tags: javascript

O que significa o termo "typeof module", em javascript?

Exemplo:

```
function(c,p){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=c.document?p(c,!0):function(c){if(!c.document)throw Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return p(c)}
```

Comment: Dica: esse código não é dos mais fáceis de ler porque foi minificado. Então, se quer entendê-lo, antes de mais nada é melhor passar por [alguma ferramenta de reformatação automática](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!! Procurei uma ferramenta desta por toda a web e não encontrei, sou muito grato pelo seu comentário!!

Comment: Mesmo depois de passar por lá o código não é nada legível. Compare com as ~25 linhas de código [do original](https://github.com/david-mark/jquery/blob/master/src/wrapper.js) (linhas 15-41).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse trecho de código está testando se a variável `module` existe ou não - provavelmente para detectar se o código está executando no *browser* ou num ambiente Node.js.

O operador [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) diz qual é o tipo de uma variável. Se ela não existir, o valor dessa expressão é `undefined`:

```js
var a = 10;
var b = "teste";
var c = { foo:"bar" };

console.log(typeof a); // "number"
console.log(typeof b); // "string"
console.log(typeof c); // "object"
console.log(typeof d); // "undefined"
```

Nesse exemplo, o código `"object"==typeof module` verifica qual o tipo da variável `module` e compara com `"object"`. Se for verdadeiro, é porque essa variável existe e é um objeto, se for falso é porque provavelmente ela não existe (embora possa existir e ter outro tipo). Na expressão citada, um resultado falso vai fazer com que o comando pare por aí (curto circuito), enquanto um verdadeiro irá executar o código que está à direita do `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` é um operador de javascript que permite ver o tipo de uma variável.

```
"object"==typeof module
```

Ou normalmente escrito como `typeof module == "object"` verifica se a variável module é um objeto.

A mesma coisa um pouco mais á frente:

```
&& "object" == typeof module.exports
```

Sabendo que `module` é um objeto, vamos agora verificar se `module.exports` também é um objeto.

Exemplificação:

```js
var var1 = "ola";
var var2 = 10;
var var3 = { };

console.log(typeof var1);
console.log(typeof var2);
console.log(typeof var3);

console.log(typeof var2 == "object");
console.log(typeof var3 == "object");
```

Comment: Mestre [Yoda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187597) manda lembranças ;)